# Operator "Any" resulting in error when I check if has an item already added

Tags: list, kotlin

I'm trying to check if in an list has a item already added, so, for that I'm using the `any` operator:

```
val cartList: ArrayList<CartModel> = generalFunctions.getSharedPreferencesArray(ApplicationConstants.UTILS.sharedPreferencesCartKey) ?: ArrayList()
          val hasFurnitureAdded = cartList.any {
                        it.furniture == furniture
                    }
```

But I'm getting the error:

`com.nomargin.gosuite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.nomargin.gosuite, PID: 11866 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nomargin.gosuite.util.models.FurnitureModel cannot be cast to com.nomargin.gosuite.util.models.CartModel`

How can I fix that?

The  `FurnitureModel`:

```
@Parcelize
data class FurnitureModel(
     val furnitureName: String,
     val furniturePrice: Float,
     val furnitureCategory: ArrayList<String>,
     val furnitureRate: Float,
     val isBestSeller: Boolean = false,
     val furnitureImage: Int = R.drawable.standard_furniture
) : Parcelable
```

The  `CartModel`:

```
data class CartModel(
     var furniture: FurnitureModel,
     var furnitureQuantity: Int
```

)

Comment: in this part of the code `it.furniture == furniture`, where does the second `furniture` come from? Is it a `FurnitureModel` or a `CartModel`?

Comment: sorry about that, is a `FurnitureModel` that comes from `SharedPreferences`

Comment: that means that the error is not on that line, but on the line above. Are you sure that `generalFunctions.getSharedPreferencesArray(ApplicationConstants.UTILS.sharedPreferencesCartKey)` returns an `ArrayList<CartModel>` and not an `ArrayList<FurnitureModel>`? If you remove the explicit type, what does the IDE suggest there?